# getjson method is not working when deployed in sharepoint 2010

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint-2010

I am new to sharepoint 2010 and javascript. I am struggling with below issue from quite a few days, I really appreciate if anybody give me the solution.

I have application developed in HTML5 using javascript which needs to deployed in sharepoint 2010 through visual web part. When I run the application without deploying in sharepoint it runs fine however when I deploy the application in sharepoint 2010 it does not loads the data. I debugged the application using VS2010 and found that my getjson method is not working.

I have used jsonp calls but it won't worked for me.

Is there any way to know why getjson/jsonp calls fails?

One of my friend told me to place cross domain policy in sharepoint 2010 root folder which will solves the problem.  What is this cross domain policy what it contains  and where to place this in sharepoint?

Answer (score 0):

Can think of a few things... since the code is not posted here, here is what may help.

I did not have to use any cross domian policy and getJSON works fine. This is the way I call it.

```
jQuery.getJSON("url_to_the_jsponp_data?callback=?", function(jdata) {

});
```

You can also try to use a different variable for jQuery like this to avoid any conflicts.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$j = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

If you are getting the data as text you have to use

```
jQuery.parseJSON(jsondata);
```

OR

```
JSON.parse(jsondata);
```

I am using jquery-1.7.1.min.js